# Slow OTRS 2.4.12 on new vm

Tags: perl, apache2, otrs

I'm moving my old OTRS installation to a fresh server. In a later step, I
want to upgrade to a newer version.

```
New VM: Fresh Debian stable 64bit, dedicated mysql-server 5.6, OTRS 2.4.12
Old VM: Old Debian stable 32bit, small localhost mysql, OTRS 2.4.12
```

The old server is quite fast, the new is very slow:

```
Response::Agent: 64s taken (URL:Action=AgentTicketQueue&QueueID=2&View=)
Response::Agent: 63s taken (URL:Action=AdminLog)
Response::Agent: 64s taken (URL:Action=AgentTicketQueue&QueueID=2&View=)
Response::Agent: 64s taken (URL:Action=AdminLog)
Response::Agent: 64s taken (URL:Action=AgentTicketQueue&QueueID=2&View=)
Response::Agent: 63s taken (URL:Action=AdminLog)
Response::Agent: 64s taken (URL:Action=AgentTicketQueue&QueueID=2&View=)
Response::Agent: 64s taken (URL:Action=AdminLog)
Response::Agent: 64s taken (URL:Action=AdminSysConfig&Subaction=Edit&SysConfigSubGroup=Core&SysConfigGroup=Framework&)
Response::Agent: 63s taken (URL:Action=AdminLog)
Response::Agent: 66s taken (URL:Action=AdminSysConfig&Subaction=Update)
Response::Agent: 64s taken (URL:Action=AdminSysConfig&Subaction=Edit&SysConfigSubGroup=Core::PerformanceLog&SysConfigGroup=Framework&)
```

perl_module is loaded:

```
apache2ctl -M
  Loaded Modules:
  core_module (static)
  ....
  perl_module (shared)
```

I use the  apache2-httpd-new.include.conf and modified the otrs-2.4.12/scripts/apache2-perl-startup.pl:

```
use DBD::mysql ();
use Kernel::System::DB::mysql;
```

I checked the DNS records, I checked the AdminLog and now I have no other ideas. CheckMXRecord is disabled

Answer (score 0):

No clue why, but for the future DenverCoder9:

I installed the Apache2 DBD perl module:

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install Apache::DBI'
```

and changed the apache2-perl-startup.pl

```
use CGI (); CGI->compile(':all');
#use CGI ();
#CGI->compile(':cgi');
use CGI::Carp ();

use Apache::DBI ();
Apache::DBI->connect_on_init('DBI:mysql:otrs;host=loadbalancer', 'otrs', '....');
use DBI ();
```

and now it is as fast as the old system. I already migrated the old database to the new dedicated mysqlserver but this was not part of the problem.

Comment: Sometimes, it is again slow and takes 61 secs. The next request or concurrent requests are fast. I don't understand why :(